# Rails 3- Active Admin (Formtastic), set column Width

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic, activeadmin

I am customizing the index form in active admin.
I have some columns like:

```
column :id
column :name
```

I want to set the width of those columns.
Is there an easy way?

Comment: I found this, but don't understand how to implement it: http://rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/master/ActiveAdmin/Views/Columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to wait for a version of active_admin that offers the feature Greg Bell talks about in https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/63

There is currently not an 'easy way' to do this.

Comment: Any of the other answers that actually offer a solution or workaround are better than this accepted answer

Answer (score 19):

for example:

```
column :name do |name|
   div :class => "name" do 
     name  
   end  
end
```

then in `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss` file:

```
div.name { width: 500px; }
```

this should work I guess

Answer (score 3):

No need to create any div class. For:

```
column :name
```

In `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss` file write:

```
.active_admin {
  .index_as_table {
    td.name {
      max-width: 150px;
      min-width: 100px;
    }
  }
}
```

To set the max-width of the columns admin panel wide write:

```
.active_admin {
  .index_as_table {
    td {
      max-width: 150px;      
    }
  }
}
```

If you're using other index renderers, just have a look the source html and tweak the active admin stylesheet accordingly.

Comment: though this does in fact work. if you have two names.  Like name of author and name of book, it breaks. You'd have to have the same width for both.